# Why can't I achive writting with `write` system-call in linux?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

First things first:

```
format ELF

section '.text' executable

public _start
_start:
    ; OPENNIN FILE DESCRIPTOR FOR A PATH -->
    mov ebx, logfile
    mov eax, 5
    mov ecx, 64
    mov edx, 777o
    int 0x80

    ; JUNT `STRLEN` -->
    mov edi, ebx
    mov ebx, eax
    xor ecx, ecx
    not ecx
    xor eax, eax
    cld
    repne scasb
    not ecx

    ; WRITTING INTO THE FD'S FILE -->
    mov edx, ecx
    sub edi, edx
    mov ecx, edi
    lea edx, [edx]
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    ; CLOSE DESCRIPTOR -->
    mov eax, 6
    int 0x80 

    ; EXIT -->
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80

section '.data' writeable

logfile db "#!@#$%$:",0
```

The above is my code I wrote into `fasm`.
When compiling and running this piece of code (This part went well so I will not go into this.), I encounter the situation of ->
My file created (and named `#!@#$%$:` of course...), but nothing was written to it.

I cant understand the reason why anything not written into the new file!
The registers state should be just like this, as mentioned in:
https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/
And the file closed fine.

What could be the reason for this to happend?

Comment: Your code has no error checking. Also, learn to use a debugger and a system call tracer. Anyway, the problem is that you opened the file read-only. Change `mov ecx, 64` to `mov ecx, 65.`

Comment: Its have no error checking because I don't need to have those... I only wanted to use sys-calls.
I debugged it using gdb, but as you know - it does not show the name for the number gave in the function.
After your recomandation, I tried strace and it dos show me the text equivalent for the number. So - thanks. I didn't know it possible in there. @Jester

Comment: @ervervevevev If you don't check for errors, you won't notice what errors occur.

Comment: Using `strace` for error checking is normal for experiments playing with system calls, in asm or C.  Much easier than actually writing error handling, *especially* in asm.  But if you didn't know about the existence of strace, then you should have been looking up the EAX/RAX return value in one of the errno header files after using GDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`strace`(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) will tell you why immediately:

```
$ strace ./test
execve("./test", ["./test"], 0x7ffef0f1b5f0 /* 72 vars */) = 0
strace: [ Process PID=32288 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
open("#!@#$%$:", O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, 0777) = 3
write(3, "#!@#$%$:\0", 9)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(3)                                = 0
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Note the `O_RDONLY|O_CREAT`: you've opened the file as read-only, thus the subsequent `write` fails.

Comment: The error should be `EPERM`, not `EBADF` in that case.  Are you sure the `strace` log is correct?

Comment: @fuz the output is correct: the system call returns `eax==0xfffffff7`, which is `-EBADF`. And [the man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) says _"`EBADF`  fd is not a valid file descriptor or is not open for writing."_